# Remove or Change the [SSE] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[sse](/questions/tagged/sse) Can refer to:

[server-sent-events](/questions/tagged/server-sent-events) **or** *Streaming SIMD Extensions* (which is what [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) points to now)

Can we please **create the tag** [streaming-simd](/questions/tagged/streaming-simd) or something like that and ***burninate*** the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag so that it cannot be confused?

OR still create the other tag, but allow for the [sse] tag to be used for **both** types of questions.

Comment: `SSE` was created 1999 (the technology, not the tag)...so I'm all for keeping that in place, as it is rather well established [citation needed] in contrast to the fancy HTML5 thingy. I can also find no reference of `SSE` used for `Server-Sent-Events` in any official documentation of any kind (smells like the Glassfish guys started with it).

Comment: @UristMcBobby its is #1 on the list for what `SSE` _might_ be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA, and if that's what Wikipedia says, it must be true. Right? ;)

Comment: @Rob oh, but of course :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't agree with this. Googling SSE shows "Streaming SIMD Extensions" as the very first hit for me.

So "SSE" is much more used for that than "server sent events". Not to mention there are many more questions with [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) than [server-sent-events](/questions/tagged/server-sent-events).

I also haven't seen anyone mistagging [server-sent-events](/questions/tagged/server-sent-events) with [sse](/questions/tagged/sse). So I don't think it's a problem.

What ***can*** use some cleaning up is the # of "SSE" tags.

- [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) - 379
- [sse2](/questions/tagged/sse2) - 65
- [sse3](/questions/tagged/sse3) - 8
- [sse4](/questions/tagged/sse4) - 9